# Know which rect has been collided in a collidelist

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to find a specific rect in a collidelist when my bullet touches the rect.
I have 92 rects, and each of them are given a type : "Opaque", "Transparent".
When I create the rects at the launch of the game, I place them in a list, to after test the collidelist. And an other list which contains all the types in order.
Like

```
collide_wall_list = [rect,rect,rect,rect]
#Each rect is a pygame.draw.rect

wall_type_list = ["Opaque","Opaque","Opaque","Transparent"]
```

They are created in order, so the 2nd rect is the 2nd type.

```
if new_bullet_list[n].collidelist(collide_wall_list) != -1:
```

This is to test if any of my bullet is colliding with the list of rects.
Now, the problem is that with the collidelist, we can't know WHICH of the rects are being collided.
Do you have any idea how to know which of the rects are being collided ? And then for the type it will be easy, because the rects and the types are in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

collidelist returns the index of the first collision, or -1 if no collision occurs:

*"Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned."*

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have obviously a function that checks if a collision happened, that returns -1 ? I don't know. But here's my idea; just try to make your function look like this:

```
int IsCollision( "all your variables" + int n) { // n = the current rect's number
         if ("collision" == true) {
               return n;
            } else {
            return 0;
           }
}
```

of course now you need to change your other line to:

```
if new_bullet_list[n].collidelist(collide_wall_list) != 0: //colidelist will return "n", so the number of your rectangle. If that number is not equal to zero, a collision happened with your n'th rect.
```

Comment: My function already exists, it is the pygame.rect.collidelist() :p

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve what op is describing in the current version of Pygame called
collideobjects() Per the docs it checks a sequence for collisions and either returns the first object that is found to collide or if no collisions are found returns None.
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collideobjects

I figured I would update the answer to this question as it still shows up when searching for Pygame solutions.